# Elastic search aggregation using multiple IDs

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a requirement where we need to aggregate (count) for the following
The system logs the Order ID, Status and Time. The order status gets updated.
I need to get the count of order statuses. Using the latest order status. (i.e. Order should not be repeated in count)

Again it's like getting the MAX date of each order and counting the statuses.

Comment: Can you give more info? like what queries have you tried? what does mapping for this fields looks like?

Comment: ORDER.status can be a terms aggs query. But ORDER Number is not unique. Need to capture the ORDER Number (along with the latest status) having the latest status and aggregate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.